# Access denied when attempting to save Datagridview column export to PDF

Tags: c#

I am trying to save PDF file directly to the default my Documents folder but it shows file access is denied at path C:\Users\Administrator\Documents. I have tried by making document folder permission access to everyone on the security Tab. How we can solve this error?

**Code**

```
private void btnpdf_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    PdfPTable pdfTable = new PdfPTable(dataGridView2.Columns.Count);
    pdfTable.DefaultCell.Padding = 3;
    pdfTable.WidthPercentage = 100;
    pdfTable.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_LEFT;
    //Add header
    foreach (DataGridViewColumn column in dataGridView2.Columns)
    {
        PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(column.HeaderText));
        pdfTable.AddCell(cell);
    }
    //add data row
    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView2.Rows)
    {
        foreach(DataGridViewCell celli in row.Cells)
        {
            if (celli.Value == null)
            {
                pdfTable.AddCell("");

            }
            else
            {
                pdfTable.AddCell(new Phrase(celli.Value.ToString()));
            }
        }
    }

    string folderPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);
    if (!Directory.Exists(folderPath))
    {
        Directory.CreateDirectory(folderPath);
    }

    //SaveFileDialog sfd = new SaveFileDialog();
    //sfd.Filter = "PDF (*.pdf)|*.pdf";
    //sfd.FileName = "Output.pdf";

    //if (sfd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    //{
    //}
    using (FileStream sr = new FileStream(folderPath , FileMode.Create))
    {
        Document pdfDoc = new Document(PageSize.A4, 10f, 20f, 20f, 10f);
        PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, sr);
        pdfDoc.Open();
        pdfDoc.Add(pdfTable);
        pdfDoc.Close();
        sr.Close();
    }

    MessageBox.Show("pdf file save to document");
    
}
```

Comment: Just because you are logged in as Administrator doesn't mean your application is running as admin.

Comment: Tried by running application on Administrator.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to start your stream directly to a folder. In other words, you are telling C# to write your file without a file specified.

Simply change

```
string folderPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments); //Path to my documents
if (!Directory.Exists(folderPath))
{
    Directory.CreateDirectory(folderPath);
}
```

To

```
string folderPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments); //Path to my documents
if (!Directory.Exists(folderPath))
{
    Directory.CreateDirectory(folderPath);
}
folderPath = Path.Combine(folderPath, "report.pdf"); //Create report.pdf in my documents
```

---

Or if you want to prompt the user with where to save the file you can use

```
SaveFileDialog sfd = new SaveFileDialog();
sfd.Filter = "PDF (*.pdf)|*.pdf";
sfd.FileName = "Output.pdf";

if (sfd.ShowDialog() != DialogResult.OK)
{
    // IF CANCEL IS SELECTED WHEN THE DIALOG RESULT COMES UP EXIT, BECAUSE NO FILE WAS SELECTED TO BE SAVED
    return;
}

folderPath = sfd.FileName;
```

Comment: its slow.it takes time on both pdf and excel file to save.

Comment: That would be a new question or something you should figure out on your own. The original question has been resolved. However, my advice is to set breakpoints every few lines and figure out what is causing it to be slow. Then see if there is an alternative function. However, the filestream is most likely **not** the slowdown.

Comment: return just goes out of loop

Comment: Yep. If cancel is selected the `sfd.FileName` become an empty string. Which will lead to the same error that you had before. So the logic is if the DialogResult is not OK (e.g the user clicks cancel instead of ok) then the user does not want to continue so exit the function, and do not attempt to save.